# why the error on browser console 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined'

Tags: angular, redux

```js
import {ILogin} from './properties';
import { LOGIN, LOGOUT } from './actions';

export interface ILoginState {
    login: ILogin[];
}

export const INITIAL_STATE: ILoginState = {
    login: []
}

export function rootReducer(state: ILoginState, action): ILoginState{
    switch(action.type){
        case LOGIN: 
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                login: state.login.concat(Object.assign({}, action.loginInfo))
            })

        case LOGOUT:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                login: state.login.filter(t => t.uname !== action.uname)
            })   
    }
}
```

why is it showing the error 'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined'.
is there any problem with state object?

Comment: Can you post what your `ILogin` interface/type looks like?

Comment: Seems like `login` property of `state` is not initialized.